# python list compare error

Tags: python

I am comparing two lists and I am getting this error `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

python

```
if all(value.lower() in mp3meta for value.lower() in search_key):
  #do stuff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Is a pretty clear error message

```
for value.lower() in search_key):
```

value.lower() is a function call not a variable hence it cant be assigned a value in the loop.

Try this :

```
if all(value in mp3meta for value in [value.lower() for value in search_key]) :
```

This is not the best way to do this. Python usually leads to pretty clean code.

Comment: How can I lowercase each compared key in each iteration then?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to lowercase the string in the assignment expression. You don't need to do that.

Try this instead:

```
if all(value.lower() in mp3meta for value in search_key):
```

This makes the this equivalent to:

```
def test(searchkey, mp3meta):
    for value in search_key:
        if value.lower() in mp3meta:
            return True

if test(searchkey, mp3meta):
```

Your attempt at the loop tried to do this instead:

```
for value.lower() in search_key:
```

which is a syntax error in Python.